# How to open konsole in fullscreen mode?

Tags: terminal, konsole, fullscreen

Is there a command or better yet a setting in the config file to allow me to open konsole (the KDE terminal emulator) in fullscreen mode?

Comment: Just addition, you can toggle fullscreen by pressing F11 key, as described at Menu -> Settings -> Full Screen Mode (F11), same like firefox, chrome, gedit...etc

Answer (score 4):

You can open Konsole in fullscreen mode with `konsole --fullscreen` (That should work only with KDE 4.11 and newer).

However, I assume that you want to be able to open Konsole in fullscreen mode with just clicking icon somewhere, maybe in taskbar. To achieve that, do the following steps:

1. Copy `/usr/share/applications/konsole.desktop` to either

   - `/usr/share/applications/konsole-custom.desktop` (in case you have root rights)

   or

   - `~/.local/share/applications/konsole-custom.desktop` (in case you don't have root rights. Also, remember to check that this directory is in your `$PATH`, and if it's not, add it there).
2. Replace the line `Exec=konsole` with `Exec=konsole --fullscreen` in the file you just copied.
3. To place that just created Konsole "launcher" to KDE's taskbar, just drag the `.desktop` file you just created from the Dolphin window to taskbar.

Then click the launcer, and Konsole should open in fullscreen mode.

Comment: `konsole --fullscreen` did not work, seems like my version of KDE is too old (I'm on FC18), but thanks, I'll switch to FC20 soon and I'll mark your answer as the solution if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The KDE Konsole Full Screen Mode is not the same as the traditional "full screen" text mode, it is just a maximized application in KDE.

You can set a good large font, hide the menu bar and the tab bar, and you can set the profile to save the window size-and-location.

Comment: I already hid the menu and tab bar and set the profile to save the size and location. I still have to press the shortcut to go into fullscreen each time I open a new konsole window. I want it to start in fullscreen though, like xterm with its "-fullscreen" command line option.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/)? You can set its size to 100% and it will go full screen when you press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
Alternately you can <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> to switch consoles <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> should take you back to KDE (this depends on your configuration).